# Passing two dimensional arrays to functions in Rust

Tags: arrays, function, rust

Does anybody know how to pass a two dimensional array to function in Rust? The function needs to change values of array.

This is how I create array:

```
let state=[mut [mut 0u8, ..4], ..4];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*(nb: rust 0.5, which wasn't yet out when this question was asked)*

The stupid way to find out the type of a value is to write a function with the *wrong* type, then try to pass it.  :)

```
fn func(state: int) {}
```

produces:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `int` but found `[mut [mut u8]/4]/4` (expected int but found vector)
```

So that's your type.  Except it's not actually written like that any more, so it seems there's a bug in this output.  So much for just asking the compiler.  You actually want:

```
fn func(state: [mut [mut u8 * 4] * 4]) { ... }
```

But `mut` inside vectors is sorta deprecated; you can get the same effect by making the variable itself `mut`.  That brings us to:

```
let mut state = [[0u8, ..4], ..4];
func(state);

// ...

fn func(state: [[u8 * 4] * 4]) {}
```

And if you want to actually change `state` inside the function, you'll need a mutable pointer to it, so finally:

```
let mut state = [[0u8, ..4], ..4];
func(&mut state);

// ...

fn func(state: &mut [[u8 * 4] * 4]) {}
```